# Creating an object with the array of a split string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an object using an array that is made using split():

```
var x = "one two";
var y = x.split(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/)
```

This gives me an array

```
[one, two]
```

Now I want to use that array and create an object using those values, e.g. {one:two}

The following doesn't work:

```
var z = {};
z.y[0] = y[1];
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code tries to get the property `y` on the object `z` (which doesn't exist), then attempts to use that values as an array and set its first element to `y[1]`. Obviously, `z.y` is not an array, it is `undefined`, so it fails.

You need to use array access notation:

```
z[y[0]] = y[1];
```

This will use `y[0]` as a key instead of interpreting it literally.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted!